# How can i register a domain name without an online host?

Tags: apache2

I don't believe in paid online hosts which is why i use apache
but now i need a domain name/host name for it so other people can connect to my website without seeing my actual ip address, is there any software or methods to host my own domain name on ubuntu?
PS when i say online host i either refer to a web host or a domain register like godaddy or dyn. also if there isn't any software is there any free registers that i can get a .com domain without any subdomains?

Comment: This is not related to Ubuntu. You need to register a domain. But everyone will see your IP either way ;-)

Comment: I'm kind of relating it to ubuntu by asking if there is any software that i can do this without using an online domain register.

Comment: also if there isn't any software i was hoping if there is any free ones where i can get a .com domain without any sub domains at the beginning.

Comment: There is no software on any OS that can register a domain without applying somewhere. It is not done by software. Someone needs to add your domain to DNS servers.

Comment: Okay so there isn't any software that can do this exactly but is it possible i can create my own DNS server and add a domain?

Comment: You can use your own DNS server with your personal domain. But it will work only for those who will use your DNS in network settings ;-) Why not read some article about DNS instead of asking at a wrong place?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can ask people to add your hostname to their `/etc/hosts` file. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)) for details.

However, this is an obsolete technique, replaced by widely accepted [Domain Name System (DNS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System). Some information on how to get a DNS record can be found at http://www.spinfold.com/how-to-buy-a-domain-name/.

Either way, people will be able to see your IP address. It is a necessary condition to provide any content over the Internet.